# How to save multiple instances of data using one form in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, forms

I have built a screen where an administrator can add and edit users. I'm able to add users without issue, but when I was testing how users can be edited, I noticed that if I have more than one user, I'm only be able to edit the last user thats listed. I'm unable to edit any other user.

Here is my code:

```
<?php foreach ($personel as $person) { ?>
<div id="edituser<?php echo $person['Personel']['id']; ?>" class="modal" style="display:none;">
    <?php
        $edituserformname = "editUser" + $person['Personel']['id'];
    ?>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
        <h3>Edit User - <?php echo $person['Personel']['firstname']; ?> <?php echo $person['Personel']['surname']; ?></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body iframed">
        <?php echo $
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->create('Personel', array(
                'class' => 'form-horizontal',
                'id' => $edituserformname
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('id', array(
                'type' => 'hidden',
                'value' => $person['Personel']['id']
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('firstname', array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'First Name',
                'class' => 'span5',
                'value' => $person['Personel']['firstname']
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('surname', array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Surname',
                'class' => 'span5',
                'value' => $person['Personel']['surname']
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('email', array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'E-Mail',
                'class' => 'span5',
                'value' => $person['Personel']['email']
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('companyid', array(
                'type' => 'hidden',
                'value' => $company['Company']['id']
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('accesslevel', array(
                'label' => 'Access Level',
                'options' => $roles,
                'empty' => 'Select Access Level',
                'class' => 'span5',
                'value' => $person['Personel']['accesslevel']
            ));
            $pocval = array('1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No');
            echo $this->Form->input('poc', array(
                'label' => 'Point of Contact?',
                'options' => $pocval, 
                'value' => $person['Personel']['poc']
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('password', array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Password',
                'class' => 'span5',
                'value' => $company['Personel']['password']
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('telephone', array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Telephone',
                'class' => 'span5',
                'value' => $company['Personel']['telephone']
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('type', array(
                'type' => 'hidden',
                'value' => '0'
            ));
         ?>
     </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <?php
        echo $this->Form->submit('Save & Close', array(
                'type' => 'submit',
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                'id' => 'editusermodal'
            ));
        echo $this->Form->end();
         ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

How can I fix this issue? I had an idea about using iFrame's but I'm reluctant to use this method. I'd rather be able to do it through CakePHP.

Many thanks

Comment: there are as many forms here as there are items in the $personel array. you're creating a new form on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use iFrame's. It doesn't work because your Form doesn't close correctly.

The `$this->Form->create()` and `$this->Form->end()` should be outside the divs.

Try the following:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Personel', array(
        'class' => 'form-horizontal',
        'id' => $edituserformname
    ));
?>
    <div class="modal-body iframed">
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->input('id', array(
                'type' => 'hidden',
                'value' => $person['Personel']['id']
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('firstname', array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'First Name',
                'class' => 'span5',
                'value' => $person['Personel']['firstname']
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('surname', array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Surname',
                'class' => 'span5',
                'value' => $person['Personel']['surname']
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('email', array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'E-Mail',
                'class' => 'span5',
                'value' => $person['Personel']['email']
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('companyid', array(
                'type' => 'hidden',
                'value' => $company['Company']['id']
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('accesslevel', array(
                'label' => 'Access Level',
                'options' => $roles,
                'empty' => 'Select Access Level',
                'class' => 'span5',
                'value' => $person['Personel']['accesslevel']
            ));
            $pocval = array('1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No');
            echo $this->Form->input('poc', array(
                'label' => 'Point of Contact?',
                'options' => $pocval, 
                'value' => $person['Personel']['poc']
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('password', array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Password',
                'class' => 'span5',
                'value' => $company['Personel']['password']
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('telephone', array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Telephone',
                'class' => 'span5',
                'value' => $company['Personel']['telephone']
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('type', array(
                'type' => 'hidden',
                'value' => '0'
            ));
         ?>
     </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->submit('Save & Close', array(
                    'type' => 'submit',
                    'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                    'id' => 'editusermodal'
                ));
             ?>
    </div>
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->end(); 
?>
```

Comment: I've done this but it still wont save the data to the database. The form isnt being submitted.

Comment: You should try the code i posted, but without the html tags, so you will only have the `<form>...</form><form>...</form>` in the output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more than one record editing at a time you can use the following

```
$this->Form->input('ModelName.n.field_name', $options);
```

So to do all of them run this in a loop:

```
echo $this->Form->create(); // only one start
foreach($users as $k => $user) {
    echo $this->Form->id(sprintf('Personel.%s.id', $k), array(
         'value' => $user['Personel']['id']
    ));
    echo $this->Form->input(sprintf('Personel.%s.field', $k), array(
         'value' => $user['Personel']['field']
    ));

    // etc
}
echo $this->Form->end(); // only one end
```

To save them all you can use `saveAll()`

```
$this->Personel->saveAll($this->data['Personel']);
```